# creating controllers in magento

Tags: php, magento, block

I want to create a new controller, which call a block and displays it.
For now I get to call my controller but not the block.

I have in my app.code.local.Flexishore.All.controllers ProspecteController.php:

```
 <?php
class Flexishore_All_ProspecteController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initLayoutMessages('customer/session');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('prospecte');
        $this->renderLayout();
   }
  public function postAction()
    {
      ...
```

then in app.design.frontend.saver.default.layout I have flexishore.xml where I added
the following code:

```
<flexishore_prospecte_index translate="label">
        <reference name="prospecte">
            <block type="core/template" name="prospecte" template="flexishore/prospecte.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </flexishore_prospecte_index>
```

finally in app.design.frontend.saver.default.template.flexishore I have prospecte.phtml, he contains the form that I want to display.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Custom Module Creator Link](http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/#.UZHxAEqCWSo) Click this link to create any sort of custom module. Your problem will certainly sort things out.

Comment: I found a solution, but your link will be very useful to me in the future.

Comment: Yes it's very useful I create my every module using this module.Cheers :)